# Limit number of characters counted for getChar loop in C

Tags: c, input

I'm making a small program that takes input from the user and display's how many times each vowel occurs in the input (as well as the number of digits). The one thing I can't figure out how to do is limit it so that only the first 50 characters are counted (as in, if the user enters more than 50 digits, ignore any past 50).

I've tried having a count variable that increments on every iteration but that doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int input, digits = 0, a = 0, e = 0, i = 0, o = 0, u = 0, count = 0;
    printf("Enter a string of chars. Hit control - D to end. Thanks. \n");
    while(count < 51){
    while ((input = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch(input) {
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9': digits += 1; break;
            case 'a':
            case 'A': a += 1; break;
            case 'e':
            case 'E': e += 1; break;
            case 'i':
            case 'I': i += 1; break;
            case 'o':
            case 'O': o += 1; break;
            case 'u':
            case 'U': u += 1; break;
        }
            count += 1;
       }

    }
    printf("a:%d e:%d i:%d o:%d u:%d digits:%d\n",a,e,i,o,u,digits);
}
```

Comment: "I've tried having a count variable that increments on every iteration but that doesn't work". Please show your attempt. We can't tell you where you went wrong if you don't show the code. And when you do please describe the problem in more detail than "it doesn't work". For example, describe the sample input, the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour.

Comment: A simple `while ((count++ < NUMBER) && ((input = getchar()) != EOF))` must work, why doesn't it?

Comment: That did work, i'm sorry. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your inner while loop will continue to loop until `EOF` before it comes out of the loop and increments and checks your counter. Put the check for the counter in the same `while` loop, as in one of the comments.

Delete `while(count < 51) {` and the closing parenthesis, and make your `while` statement:

```
while ((count < 51) && (input = getchar()) != EOF) {
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to do is limit it so that only the first 50 characters are counted

Drop the `while(count < 51){`.  Change select increments to add 0 or 1

```
#define LIMIT 50
// digits += 1;
digits += count < LIMIT;
...
a += count < LIMIT;
...
count += 1;
```